# Amplitude of the process $q \bar q \rightarrow \tau^+ \tau^-H$

Tags: standard-model, quantum-electrodynamics, scattering, phase-space, scattering-cross-section

I want calculate the cross section of the process $q \bar q \rightarrow \tau^+ \tau^-H$, where the Higgs takes the $vev$. My question is: if the Higgs takes the $vev$ the amplitude  of the process is equal to $vev$ multiplied for the amplitude of the process $q \bar q\rightarrow\tau^+ \tau^-$: $A_{q \bar q \rightarrow \tau^+ \tau^-H}=vevA_{q \bar q\rightarrow\tau^+ \tau^-}$?

[image]

Comment: Can you explain *what* "where the Higgs takes the  means? Can you write, e.g., respective Feynman diagrams? *H* is a real field, and a very heavy one, at that....

Comment: @CosmasZachos It means when the Higgs is in the minimum of the potential. I added a picture of the Feynman diagrams of the process that I'm studying

Comment: The diagrams you wrote don’t exist: there are only four external legs; no real Higgs particle.

Comment: @CosmasZachos But if I wanted to write the transition amplitude of these diagrams it would be  v x $A_{q \bar q \rightarrow \tau^+ \tau^-}$?

Comment: So you want to compare perturbation theory on the false vacuum to that of the real vacuum? There is a boatload of context missing there. What text is even talking about that?